# DIV as CSS Properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax

for my upcoming Project i use the parallaxjs effect. As you know, it uses multiple css background layers which change the position at scrolling. What i want to, that i use div layers instead of css defined backgrounds.

```
function Move(){ 
    var pos = $window.scrollTop(); //position of the scrollbar

    //if the first section is in view...
    if($firstBG.hasClass("inview")){
        //call the newPos function and change the background position
        $firstBG.css({'backgroundPosition': newPos(50, windowHeight, pos, 900, 0.3)}); 
    }
```

Is there any way to have a div layer (for example with a lightbox) instead of the background-image css?
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: i think yes you can. just use divs with `position:absolute` and then change the top property. but if you want more help, please provide your html code.

Comment: well i just use the sample code of http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/
it moves the bg.css of each class.

Comment: sorry im a little bit confused. so you are using the sample code from the link but not the plugin?

Comment: no, its a demo file! i used it and changed the preferences... that code snippet above is that part for each layer with the background image. what i want to is the layer doesnt change the background properties! it should change the content itself...

Comment: i cant help myself but i cant find neither your posted snippet nor any of this functions (`Move` and `newPos`) in this page. maybe you gave me the wrong link? if not, i can just theoretically help you. I would first set your "background-divs" to `position:absolute;` (of course ajust the `top` and `left` properties to set its position right). after that, change the css function in your `Move()` to `$firstBG.css({'top': newPos(.....`

Comment: oh i see, the developer changed the code of the parallax.js. i didnt notice. i will try it with the new code and your possible solution. thanks for your help, i appreciate that very much! i will inform you later :)